# How to display model popup after refreshing page?

Tags: jsf, user-interface, jsf-2, primefaces, popup

Model popup is closing while refreshing (after pressing F5) the page
please tell me how to display it after refreshing also.
i'm using prime faces

```
<p:confirmDialog  closable="false" id="sessionExpiredDlg" message="Your session expired."  
                 header="#{msgs['confirmDialog.initiatingDestroyProcess.label']}" 
                 severity="alert" widgetVar="sessionExpiredConfirmation" style="z-index: 25000">
    <p:commandButton id="confirmRouteDel" value="Ok"
                                   oncomplete="sessionExpiredConfirmation.hide()" 
                                   actionListener="#{login.logoutAction}"/>

</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: Refreshing with some jsf action or with F5?

Comment: Refresh creates a new HTTP request. So session is not expired anymore. Why should this dialog still be shown?

Comment: `<p:confirmDialog/>` has a `visible` attribute, and I believe you can track page refreshes in javascript, all you need to do is get creative.

Comment: I am expected from user to press confirmation button and it's a only way to pass through session expire popup.  BalusC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When session expired your have to add some information to response for example a cookie "sessionExpired=true" and sent it to your client with response.

Then you have to render your `confirmDialog` everytime when you find in `HttpServletRequest` object that cookie.

I am understanding that you expected from user to press confirmation button and it's a only way to pass through your popup, yes? 
So then when user press button just replace cookie from request (for example by changing it's expiration date to some past value) and with next user request cookie won't come and your app won't display that popup.

By replacing `Cookie` from request I mean something like this:

```
Map<String, Object> requestCookieMap =
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestCookieMap();
Cookie sessionExpiredCookie = (Cookie) requestCookieMap.get("sessionExpired");
sessionExpiredCookie.setMaxAge(0);
```